# Better way to do multiple list comprehensions over the same range?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

At the moment my code is as follows

```
A = [matrix_x[i][:n] for i in xrange(0, n)]
B = [matrix_x[i][n:] for i in xrange(0, n)]
C = [matrix_x[i+n][:n] for i in xrange(0, n)]
D = [matrix_x[i+n][n:] for i in xrange(0, n)]
```

Is there a better way of doing this, since I am continually looping over the same xrange.  In this instance, would if be better to not use a list comprehension and just append the values to each list while in a single for loop.

```
A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]
for i in xrange(0,n):
    A.append(matrix_x[i][:n])
    B.append(matrix_x[i][n:])
    ... etc
```

Second way seems more efficient to me. What way would be more 'pythonic' or is there another way I haven't thought of

Comment: I think the interpreter is smart enough to optimize this example. You should try to time it.

Comment: For working with matrices have you considered numpy?

Comment: @Mark - I have, but this is the way I want to do it in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally prefer to iterate over the list of items itself, rather than over `xrange(len(list_of_items))` and working with the i'th item at a time. Here's how to use `zip` to look at each `(this,next)` pair in a sequence, and then build up your lists:

```
A,B,C,D = [],[],[],[]
for this_,next_ in zip(matrix_x,matrix_x[1:]):
    A.append(this_[:n])
    B.append(this_[n:])
    C.append(next_[:n])
    D.append(next_[n:])
```

And yes, you can really compact this down to a `zip` of a `zip`:

```
A,B,C,D = zip(*((this_[:n],this_[n:],next_[:n],next_[n:])
                  for this_,next_ in zip(matrix_x,matrix_x[1:])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You can use `zip()` creatively to generate all 4 lists at once, but I'd be *very* hard-pressed to call that "better".

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [(matrix_x[i][:n], matrix_x[i][n:], matrix_x[i+n][:n],matrix_x[i+n][n:])  for i in xrange(0, n)]
```

then you'd have to unpack for each element
A,B,C,D = result[x]

Although doing that with a matrix_x being a string didn't yield expected results for me.